# Añadir una imagen de la web a una página HTML

Tags: html, imagen

Quiero añadir una imagen de la web he añadido una de mi galería pero ¿se puede de la web?

```
<div align = right ><img src="animales.png" height="500" ></div>
```

Ese es el código que ocupo.

Comment: ¿Lo probaste? ¿Resultó?

Answer (score 1):

Si puedes, solo debes tener la URL completa de la imagen a ligar, quedaría algo así:

```
<div align = right ><img src="https://dogtime.com/assets/uploads/2018/10/puppies-cover.jpg" height="500" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Claro que puedes, solo agrega en

```
src="http://www.example.com/image.gif"
```

Comment: Hola Edgar MC: Bienvenido a la comunidad [es.so]. Si bien tu pregunta puede responder perfectamente a lo solicitado, te recomiendo que pases por el siguiente enlace, para que no recibe votos negativos. [answer]